# CSS nth-child for a range of elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm a bit new to using nth-child() so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm trying to use it in my css file and not directly into the html.  Below is my code - I want to highlight the first four items that populate into this list.

```
        <div class="icdcode-selector row-fluid " icdcode="@icd.ICDCode" orderID="@x" icdID="@icd.ID">
            <div class="span2 icdcode-sortable-handle">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <i class="icon-align-justify"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <span class="icd-name">@icd.ICDCode</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => icd.UserText, new { @class = "span11", id = "icd_" + Model.Encounter.DictationID.ToString() + "_" + icd.ICDCode.Replace('.', '-'), icd = icd.ICDCode })
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini icd-remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to use a class like this: `.primary-billing .div:nth-child(-n+4)`, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Please help.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code with a class of primary-billing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to change *.div* to *div* (it's an element, not a class).

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/sQCCA/

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out and came back here to respond.  But thank you for replying, I am very much appreciative of everyone responding.. :)